Why is the player getting damaged whenever either the bullet despawns or the player gets hit?
I have other code to go with this, but whenever a bullet despawns (hits the edge or times out), the player gets damaged. I haven't been able to test if the player gets damaged when they collide because of how much damage is done passively.
function shootPlayer() {
    if (!document.body.contains(enemy)) return;  // Stop if the enemy is removed

    const playerRect = player.getBoundingClientRect();
    const playerCenterX = playerRect.left + playerRect.width / 2;
    const playerCenterY = playerRect.top + playerRect.height / 2;
    const enemyRect = enemy.getBoundingClientRect();
    const enemyCenterX = enemyRect.left + enemyRect.width / 2;
    const enemyCenterY = enemyRect.top + enemyRect.height / 2;

    const angle = Math.atan2(playerCenterY - enemyCenterY, playerCenterX - enemyCenterX);

    const bullet = document.createElement('div');
    bullet.className = 'bullet';
    bullet.style.position = 'absolute';
    bullet.style.top = `${enemyCenterY}px`;
    bullet.style.left = `${enemyCenterX}px`;
    document.body.appendChild(bullet);

    const bulletSpeed = 5;
    const bulletDamage = 5;

    function moveBullet() {
        let bulletTop = parseFloat(bullet.style.top);
        let bulletLeft = parseFloat(bullet.style.left);

        bulletTop += bulletSpeed * Math.sin(angle);
        bulletLeft += bulletSpeed * Math.cos(angle);

        bullet.style.top = `${bulletTop}px`;
        bullet.style.left = `${bulletLeft}px`;

        console.log(`Bullet Position: (${bulletLeft}, ${bulletTop})`);

        // Simple collision detection with the player
        if (
            bulletLeft >= playerRect.left &&
            bulletLeft <= playerRect.right &&
            bulletTop >= playerRect.top &&
            bulletTop <= playerRect.bottom
        ) {
            decreasePlayerHealth(bulletDamage);
            bullet.remove();
            console.log('Bullet hit the player.');
            return;
        }

        // Check if the bullet is out of bounds and remove it
        if (bulletTop < 0 || bulletTop > window.innerHeight || bulletLeft < 0 || bulletLeft > window.innerWidth) {
            bullet.remove();
            console.log('Bullet despawned.');
            return;
        }

        // Continue moving the bullet
        requestAnimationFrame(moveBullet);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(moveBullet);
}


I've tried a few options with conditions in the if statement. None worked. The decreasePlayerHealth function should only run when the bullet hits the player.

Can't really tell without all the context. But it seems like there might be some weird behaviour in your code because you're calling "requestAnimationFrame" at the end of shootPlayer() and at the end of moveBullet, which is defined inside the other.
FYI: When posting on stackoverflow, you should always narrow your problem down to the main issue you're having, without just pasting your whole code and expecting people to solve your program. + use a page like jsfiddle.net to give an example.

In contrast to what @steveniclas told you, please do not use jsfiddle - use a stack snippet instead and include all relevant code right into your question. By providing a link to a jsfiddle (or another online editor for that purpose) future readers cannot be sure that the code is still reachable. Read How to create a MRE for more information.

I find collision to be very tricky. I can think of a few tricks to help make it work:
1: Check if decreasePlayerHealth() is being called anywhere else.
2: In your collision detection, check if your bullet is out of bounds first, then do an else if statement on your player collision detection. Sometimes changing the order of your code will work.
I have built game physics before, and I know it isn't easy, so collect as much necessary data as you can, and switch your code around, and hope for the best. Sometimes a good ol' switch-a-rue makes things clearer on what is going on.
Hope this helps.
